# How to delete a map from the GRASS interface?

Tags: grass-gis

I want to delete a map that I generated from GRASS. I tried removing a map from the "Map Layers for each display" tab in the GRASS GIS Layer Manager, but it only removed the map from the list and not deleted. I want to delete the map totally that it won't appear as an option in when I load the maps in the workspace (Workspace>Load Map Layers). How is it done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options:

`g.remove` - Removes maps by name.

`g.mremove` - Removes many maps using wildcards (ie. temp*).

Answer (score 5):

And from the GUI:

```
File->Manage Maps and Volumes->Delete
```